# Why wouldn't an embedded silverlight control work in a page?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have a silverlight application project in my solution.  The other project is a web application project that has a .xap file in ClientBin.

When I created the silverlight project, it asked if I wanted the asp.net application to host it (and I said yes).

In the root directory, there is a test page for the silverlight control.  That loads the control.

In another directory, I insert the SAME asp markup to get the silverlight control to launch again.

Nothing happens.

Why would the silverlight launch on one page and not on the other?  Can people help point me to documentation about dependencies that I might not know about?

I've put a reference to Silverlight.js on the page as well.

Here's the markup:

```
 <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="../ClientBin/Editor.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>  

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After explicitly specifying the width and height in the stylesheet, it's showing up now.
Duh!